# Which of these distinctions in modal terms overlap each other (if any)?

Tags: kant, modal-logic

Ori Simchen is an author who has published work on analysis of a [difference (sustainable or not) between *general* and *particular* possibilities.](https://www.academia.edu/2987019/Actualist_Essentialism_and_General_Possibilities) Something is particularly possible when it is possible "under the (given) circumstances," generally possible otherwise (unless impossible).

But so how far apart are that distinction, and a distinction between *direct* and *indirect* possibility? Or then how much distinguishes *categorical*/*hypothetical* from *abstract*/*concrete* or *absolute* /*relative* possibility? I get the impression that the accessibility relation in mainline modal logic can help take care of such distinctions; but so whether they can all be collapsed into different outputs of an accessibility function (so to say), or if all such divergences are important "in their own right," I don't know. I *suspect* (or at least hope) that I could reframe iterated possibility as something like "0-indirectly possible," "1-indirectly possible," and so on, and so give some value to the iteration.

But if I go that route, I also suspect that I will have to demarcate absolute from direct possibility, for example (actually, even starting out on a way to assimilate absoluteness to directness, sounds suspicious, now that I write the words down...).

**Modulo transcendental ideality:** I will quote [Kant on the specific topic of absolute possibility, to ground my question in the tradition](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3ACritique_of_Pure_Reason_1855_Meiklejohn_tr.djvu/269) (note, I am once again citing the Meiklejohn translation, for better or worse...):

> The word *absolute* is at present frequently used to denote that something can be predicated of a thing considered in itself and intrinsically. In this sense *absolutely possible* would signify that which is possible in itself (*interne*)—which is, in fact, the *least* that one can predicate of an object. On the other hand, it is sometimes employed to indicate that a thing is valid in all respects—for example, absolute sovereignty. *Absolutely possible* would in this sense signify that which is possible in all relations and in every respect; and this is the *most* that can be predicated of the possibility of a thing. Now these significations do in truth frequently coincide. Thus, for example, that which is intrinsically impossible, is also impossible in all relations, that is, absolutely impossible. But in most cases they differ from each other *toto caelo*, and I can by no means conclude that, because a thing is in itself possible, it is also possible in all relations, and therefore absolutely. Nay, more, I shall in the sequel show that absolute necessity does not by any means depend on internal necessity, and that, therefore, it must not be considered as synonymous with it. Of an opposite which is intrinsically impossible, we may affirm that it is in all respects impossible, and that, consequently, the thing itself, of which this is the opposite, is absolutely necessary; but I cannot reason conversely and say, the opposite of that which is absolutely necessary is intrinsically impossible, that is, that the absolute necessity of things is an internal necessity. For this internal necessity is in certain cases a mere empty word with which the least conception cannot be connected, while the conception of the necessity of a thing in all relations possesses very peculiar determinations.

Comment: I wish you stop reading Kant for a while and read some Spinoza or Leibniz if you only *willed* to stick to the Western branch...

Comment: how much Kant did you read?